# Router giving my PC two different public IP

Tags: networking, router, ip

When I am on Chrome or on Firefox and I go to http://whatismyip.host/ I get a public address `77.x.x.x` (the same for both browsers).

But my public IP changes when I play a game. iI shows a different IP (IP provided by regular confirmation emails sent to me automatically by the game) this difference of IPs between browsers and game is a problem in that I can't get rewards from the game’s website as it is IP address related.

All tests are done on the same PC and connection.

Comment: No, routers don't give public IPs.

Comment: Maybe your ISP does Carrier-grade NAT. Check in your router’s web interface, what does it report as the WAN IP address?

Comment: Hi, is it the 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: @AliMoukadem No,  any 192.168.x.x is NOT a public IP.

Comment: No, that sounds like your router’s internal IP address. What you want is the *external* IP address. You can only view it by access your router’s status and configuration interface, usually with a web browser.

Comment: in status, under wan and PVC4 i have this IP 10.53.22.233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your router apparently displays an IP address in `10.0.0.0/8` as its WAN IP address, your ISP is most certainly doing [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). It basically works like your local router does, hiding a whole network behind a single IP address.

Except that your ISP probably has load balancing in place. That means there are multiple public IP addresses that traffic will appear to originate from. This is what you’re observing.

There is nothing you can do.

You could try contacting the game developers because an IP address is no longer enough to uniquely identify players. It hasn’t been for over a decade.

Comment: Oh, I see now, I understand the problem better now, so some of my traffic goes through an address and some through another adress, correct ?

Comment: In a word, yes.  What you have is X number of users, with all their traffic split across Y public IP addresses.   This is done so that X can be significantly greater than Y, without causing too much of a bottleneck.